# How do i feed an Object Name into a varchar via For Loop in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'am an SQL rookie and just started my Apprenticeship in the CMD Team of my Company.
It's my first time working with Oracle SQL-dev and  I never coded Functions/Procedures in SQL before
So my Sensei gave me a task to solve for myself which is:

To create a stored procedure which generates views for all of my Synonyms in the current Scheme. If executed again it should Replace the current views of those Synonyms.

As second part of the task I should also add a function to DROP all the views i don't have a Synonym for

*Yes I already discussed with her if it is useful to create views this way or not*

The first thing i found out that it is not possible to create views from a stored procedure the traditional way and that i have to use a workaround method with EXEC() for example

my Sensei gave me a code Snippet to begin with:

```
FOR KO IN(SELECT * FROM all_synonyms WHERE OWNER = 'CMD_SANDBOX')
```

She told me i have to fill Variables with the Names of the Synonyms .. so far so good
it makes sense because i have to generate unique names for the views as well as the procedure to know which is the current synonym to create a view of

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE CREATE_VIEWS AS 
 DECLARE @viewCommand varchar(1000)
 DECLARE @viewName    varchar(75)
 DECLARE @synonymName varchar(75)

 SET @viewCommand = 'CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW' + @viewName + 'AS SELECT * FROM ' 
 +@synonymName 
 

BEGIN
 FOR KO IN(SELECT * FROM all_synonyms WHERE OWNER = 'CMD_SANDBOX')

  SET @synonymName = <Pointer on Synonym>
  SET @viewName =  'v_' + @synonymName
  EXEC(@viewCommand)

 END LOOP KO; 

END CREATE_VIEWS
```

Long story short...
My questions are:
How do I Point to a Certain Object without using its specific name to fill my @synonymName ?
Is the For Loop header already complete ? I kinda don't get how it works in SQL

How do you pros research this stuff? I feel pretty confident in queries but as it comes to specific things like pointing to objects or similar it is pretty hard to find out.

Comment: OK, you're learning SQL (that's a language) and use Oracle SQL Developer as a  tool to access your database. But, which database are you using? Code you posted certainly isn't Oracle, so - what is it?

Comment: Its an Oracle database as far as i know

Comment: You syntax is not valid in Oracle as you have: multiple `DECLARE`s but only a single `BEGIN`/`END` block; `@` is not valid in (unquoted) variable names; `||` is the string concatenation operator and `+` is the numeric addition operator; assignment in PL/SQL does not require `SET` and requires `:=` instead of `=`; and you want `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` and not `EXEC`. I'd say it looks more like SQL Server syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your syntax is invalid in Oracle as:

- there are multiple `DECLARE`s but only a single `BEGIN`/`END` block;
- `@` is not valid in (unquoted) variable names;
- `+` is the numeric addition operator and does not concatenate strings. To concatenate strings you want to use the `||` operator;
- assignment in PL/SQL does not require `SET` and requires `:=` instead of `=`; and
- you want `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` and not `EXEC`.

If you fix all that then there are still issues as `VIEW' + @viewName + 'AS` should have spaces between the `VIEW` and `AS` keywords and the identifier.

The syntax looks more like SQL Server than Oracle.

---

For Oracle, you want:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE CREATE_VIEWS
AS 
BEGIN
  FOR KO IN(
    SELECT synonym_name
    FROM   all_synonyms
    WHERE  OWNER = 'CMD_SANDBOX'
  )
  LOOP
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW v_' || ko.synonym_name
                   || ' AS SELECT * FROM ' || ko.synonym_name;
  END LOOP;
END CREATE_VIEWS;
/
```

Comment: Okay thank you so far for the syntax correction that helps alot 

Why is there SELECT synonym_name in the Header now ? Because i want to extraxt the Name of the Synonym instead not the Column 

Does ko.synonym_name Point to the name of the object ?

Comment: @Accelerator You are not working with pointers to synonyms, you are working with the `all_synonyms` table in Oracle's data dictionary and that table contains a single string column `synonym_name` which, unsurprisingly, contains the name of the synonym.

Comment: oooh .. now i got it ! Thx m8 
so the loop goes basically through that table creating all views of the owner